# Using a function to grab links from emails, how can I poll this function effectively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, polling, gmail-api

I have created a function in Python that (via the GMail API) will find an email sent to a specific email address (gmail alias), with a certain subject line and then pull information out of the message.

This function will only return something if it is successful, and it will return a string. I have 3 error catching statements eg.

```
try:
    gmail_service.users().messages().trash(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute() 
    print 'Message with id: %s trashed successfully.' % message['id']
except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'Could not trash ' + message['id'] + ': %s' % error
```

The code for my polling is:

```
def check_Mail(self, recipient="", loopfor=0):
    print("Loop start! loopfor = " + str(loopfor))
    while loopfor > 1:
        if get_Mail(recipient) is None:
            loopfor -= 5
            print(str(loopfor) + " seconds left in loop")
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            print("Woot, we have mail!")
            loopfor = 0
            print(get_Mail(recipient))
            #return get_Mail(recipient)
```

I am calling the `check_Mail` like so: `check_Mail("mymail@gmail.com", 30)` but the result of this method is the ouput `Loop start! loopfor = 0` and nothing else.

Why is my `int` being passed through as `0`?

Comment: _"I am calling the `check_Mail` like so: `check_Mail(30, "myemail@gmail.com")`"_. Shouldn't the integer be the _second_ argument? Like `check_Mail("myemail@gmail.com", 30)`

Comment: I see your `check_Mail` function has a `self` argument. Does this function belong to a class? If so, when you call the function, are you doing it like `MyClass.check_Mail(a,b)` or `an_instance_of_my_class.check_Mail(a,b)`? The way you do it will have an effect on which parameters will get assigned to which names. In the former, `self` will be `a` and `recipient` will be `b`; in the latter, `recipient` will be `a` and `loopfor` will be `b`.

Comment: It is part of a class, but when I run it from IDLE I don't use a class. I guess I didn't understand the `self` argument as well as I thought!

Comment: @Kevin Okay, so that fixed why my `int` was being passed as `0`. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not surprisingly, in your call:

> I am calling the check_Mail like so: check_Mail("mymail@gmail.com", 30)

Here you are passing in two arguments, but your function signature takes three arguments:

```
def check_Mail(self, recipient="", loopfor=0)
```

So what's happening is `mymail@gmail.com` is being assigned to `self`, and `30` to `recipient`:

```
    check_Mail("mymail@gmail.com", 30)
                |        ----------^
                V        V
def check_Mail(self, recipient="", loopfor=0)
```

If this method is not part of a class, remove the `self` argument from its definition. If it is part of a class, you need to pass a class instance, so either `obj.check_Mail('mymail@gmail.com', 30)` or `checkMail(obj, 'mymail@gmail.com', 30)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing by `self` that this is a class method.  The `self` method is required for class methods so the instance of the class is implicitly passed to the method when it is invoked.  if you are calling this method outside of a class (for testing, for example), your arguments are being taken in order.  So the email address is going in as `self` and the integer 30 goes in `